# Decoding problems in polkadot-js after updating of substrate version

Tags: decode, backwards-compatibility, substrate, polkadot-js

Recently I updated substrate version in our project from `monthly-2022-09` to `monthly-2022-12`. After that in out webapp that uses `polkadot-js/api` I got a decoding error on attempt to query fee details `payment_queryFeeDetails`

`type.js:57 Uncaught (in promise) Error: createType(RuntimeDispatchInfo):: decodeU8a: failed at 0x0b54020000000000000000000000… on class (index 1/3): {"_enum":{"Normal":0,"Operational":1,"Mandatory":2}}:: Unable to create Enum via index 11, in Normal, Operational, Mandatory`

It is important to mention in our project we overwrited pallet `transaction-payment`, so with new version of substrate transaction-payment remained the same.

`polkadot-js/api` version is 9.2.2

I expected query fee details will be returned and decoded properly as it was before

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].